# assets folder not bundling in xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

My fonts and images are not showing when I build from xcode, I have linked the assets folder under build phases and checked copy resources over. How can I build all my fonts and images in my assets folder?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if they're in the app bundle within the build folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...`)?

Comment: How do I get to the derived data folder? I cannot see it in the ios/build folder.

Comment: It's in your `~/Library` folder, which is hidden.  You need to do it from the shell (console).

Comment: I'm building using xcode, do I need to build using react native cli to see the bundle? I can't see any js bundle file in the build folder.

Comment: OK, so it's the *Copy Bundle Resources* bit that is failing.  I can't help more than that though.